# setting up two stores in magento with single root category

Tags: magento

We have set up two stores with two root categories and its corresponding sub categories. Usually we will move products from store 1 to store 2 after 2-3 weeks. Each time we need to tediously reassign that product to store 2's categories. Is there any way, I can set up two store with single root category?

OR Is there any way, I can automatically assign to store 2's category when I change 'website' from store1 to stor2?

Comment: Refer this tutorial, may be its hepl you : http://www.inventcommerce.com/about-us/blog/90-setting-up-multi-storefronts-on-magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set single root category for more than 1 store.

To change the root category go to

```
admin->System->Manage Stores
```

Click on Store name to edit and from edit form Choose the Root Category and save it and reindex the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case I already have 4000+ products in store1 and 2000+ products in store2. So If I use single root category like you explained, I need to change categories of current products in store 2 and manual category change of 2000+ products is a time consuming process. Also there are 100+ categories in site.

Comment: Yes, you have to move your products

Comment: I would like to show only few categories to Store 2 and Store 1 should have all categories. Can I do this if I am using single root category. If so, please explain how I can do that?

Comment: You mean to say that you want to hide empty categories?

Comment: No.I mean I need to show 5 categories in Store 1 and 3 categories in store 2. I understand that it can be done by editing code if we use custom design. I am trying to understand if there is any other methods.
Thank you Ram for answering my questions.